# error: BerkeleyDB version incompatible with BDB/HDB backends

Tags: development, macos, open-source, ldap

I've downloaded OpenLDAP sources from [Apple Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-109/) for OSX 1.9.

But I've the following error found in config.log when compiling using `make`:

```
configure:27816: checking for db.h
configure:27824: result: yes
configure:27838: checking for Berkeley DB major version in db.h
configure:27857: result: 1
configure:27865: checking for Berkeley DB minor version in db.h
configure:27884: result: 0
configure:27892: checking if Berkeley DB version supported by BDB/HDB backends
configure:27932: result: no
configure:27937: error: BerkeleyDB version incompatible with BDB/HDB backends
```

I've the lastest XCode installed.
Any clues?

Related:

- [Berkeley DB mismatch error while configuring LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010989/berkeley-db-mismatch-error-while-configuring-ldap)

Comment: Follow-up: [Compile OpenLdap problems](http://serverfault.com/q/188010/130437) at serverfault SE

Comment: (1/2) If you don't need ldap server installed on the machine, you can do `./configure --disable-slapd`. This will skip server configuration and in turn not bother with BerkleyDB since it is used by server only.

Comment: (2/2) Otherwise, you need to install BerkleyDB and update your $PATH to point to the location of BerkleyDB.